# How to run codeception api test with generated new data every test?

Tags: api, codeception

```
//variable
private $client = array(
    "title" => "Ing.",
    "name" => "Name",
    "surname" => "Surname",
    "id_number" => "123456789"
);

public function createClient($client)
{
    //creating client
    $I->sendPOST('.../api/admin/client', $client);
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(201);
    $I->seeResponseIsJson();

    //from another get API function I verify data from API resonse with data from variable input
    $I->getClient();
    $I->assertEquals($data['name'], $this->client['name']);
    $I->assertEquals($data['surname'], $this->client['surname']);
    $I->assertEquals($data['title'], $this->client['title']);
    $I->assertEquals($data['id_number'], $this->client['id_number']);
}
```

I need to create new client (with new "name", "surname" and "id_number") for every run of test.
    So I need to generate somehow with for example "Datafactory" variable data and use them for one run of test.
    For another run I need different data.

Comment: Use a faker library: https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker

Answer (score 0):

Codeception has some capabilities that will allow you to do that. You can set up a  [data factory](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/DataFactory) that will produce those object for you. Because it uses [factory muffin](http://factory-muffin.thephpleague.com/) and [faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) to create value to the objects you provide, the data will be different each time.

I've linked docs in the text of the answer. You can also check out [this codeception blog entry](http://codeception.com/10-23-2014/managing-data-with-factorymuffin.html) about factory muffin, which is used to implement data factories in codeception.